# add value if loop doesn't show value within range

Tags: vba, loops, excel

With the following code I loop through a range of about 200 cells [Range("R" & i)] to check if the Temp_Sheet.Range("B2") value is within the range. This code below works great.

Here's the problem: If the loop completes and doesn't find the value within the range, I need the B2 value added to the next blank row. How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance for the help. Can I add formatting within the loop that will trigger another sub/function if no value is found?

```
 For i = 6 To ColarLastRow
      If ChangeSheet.Range("R" & i).Value = Temp_Sheet.Range("B2") Then
         ChangeSheet.Range("G" & i) = Sum_Range
         ChangeSheet.Range("G" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 100, 0)
      Else: End If
 Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are already some good answers, but this is what I came up with....

```
 Dim ChangeSheet As Worksheet
 Dim Temp_Sheet As Worksheet
 Dim ValueFound As Boolean
 Set ChangeSheet = Sheets("ChangeSheet")
 Set Temp_Sheet = Sheets("Temp_Sheet")
 ColarLastRow = ChangeSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp).Row
 ValueFound = False

 For i = 6 To ColarLastRow
      If ChangeSheet.Range("R" & i).Value = Temp_Sheet.Range("B2") Then
         ChangeSheet.Range("G" & i) = Sum_Range
         ChangeSheet.Range("G" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 100, 0)
         ValueFound = True
      Else: End If
 Next i

 If ValueFound = False Then
    ChangeSheet.Range("R" & ColarLastRow + 1).Value = Temp_Sheet.Range("B2").Value
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set some flag inside a loop:

```
Dim AddNew As Boolean
AddNew = True

For i = 6 To ColarLastRow
      If ChangeSheet.Range("R" & i).Value = Temp_Sheet.Range("B2") Then
         ChangeSheet.Range("G" & i) = Sum_Range
         ChangeSheet.Range("G" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 100, 0)
         AddNew = False
      Else: End If
 Next i

If AddNew Then
  'place your code here  
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim counter as Integer
counter = 0
 For i = 6 To ColarLastRow
      If ChangeSheet.Range("R" & i).Value = Temp_Sheet.Range("B2") Then
         ChangeSheet.Range("G" & i) = Sum_Range
         ChangeSheet.Range("G" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 100, 0)
         Counter = counter + 1
      Else: End If
 Next i
If counter = 0 then
ChangeSheet.Range("R" & ChangeSheet.Range("R" & ChangeSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0) = Temp_Sheet.Range("B2")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dim Rng as Range
Set rng = ChangeSheet.Range("R6:R" & ColarLastRow).Find _
               (What:=Temp_Sheet.Range("B2"), LookIn:=xlValues)
'set LookIn:=xlValues, xlFormulas, as appropriate
'set MatchCase:=True or False, as appropriate
If Rng is Nothing then
  ChangeSheet.Range("R" & ColarLastRow+1).Value = 'something
  'set color here
Else
  ChangeSheet.Range("G" & rng.row) = Sum_Range
End if
```

Using the .Find will be much faster than looping through. If you need to find multiple occurrences, then after `Set Rng =` add this:

```
Set rng = ChangeSheet.Range("R6:R" & ColarLastRow).Find _
               (What:=Temp_Sheet.Range("B2"), LookIn:=xlValues)
While Not Rng is Nothing
  'do your stuff here
  Set rng = ChangeSheet.Range("R" & Rng.Row & ":R" & ColarLastRow).Find _
                 (What:=Temp_Sheet.Range("B2"), LookIn:=xlValues)
Wend
```

Comment: @FreeMan-I like the answer using 'Find', but could you clarify the second part if you wanted to loop?

Comment: @Davesexcel I've updated the 2nd, looping, code example. If you need to process each occurrence of a thing, put that processing in the `'do your stuff here` section. That code will find the first occurrence, process whatever needs to be done, then find the next occurrence. It will continue to loop until... forever, if you're not changing what you're looking for. i.e. Search for `cell.text="Fred"`, `set cell.offset(1,0).text="Flintstone"`. If it finds one cell.text = "Fred" it will loop forever since you're not changing the value of the cell....

Comment: ... You'd have to store off the 1st found cell's location, then check to see if if you've found that same cell again and stop then.